# How can I infer the key used for indexed access type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to create a helper type to infer the key used inside an indexed access type.

**Example:**

```js
type X = { foo: string, bar: boolean }
type Fn = <T extends X>(value: T) => T["foo"]
type Helper<T> = ???

type Result = Helper<Fn> // should be "foo"
```

The approach I tried is similar to the built-in `ReturnType` helper, but doesn't work so far:

```js
type Helper<Fn> = Fn extends (value: infer T) => infer R
  // R extends T[infer Key] does not work: Type 'Key' cannot be used to index type 'T'.
  ? R extends T[keyof T]
    ? T[keyof T]
    : never
  : never
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: No, but the next best thing you can do is probably [this](https://tsplay.dev/w25MzW), given the type that the key is used with. However, this means if you have another key that has a string type, that key will also be included.

Comment: This is impossible at least partly because you can't abstract over generic functions in the type system.  But this really feels like an XY problem; what is the underlying issue you're trying to solve this way?

Comment: @vr. Thanks, the TypeScript playground that you linked is exactly what I was looking for. If you write an answer here on StackOverflow, I can upvote it and mark the question as resolved.

Comment: @jcalz The original use case indeed has a different solution ;) I still found that this is an interesting enough problem to solve on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve something reasonably close using a mapped type, but this requires you to know what `T` is beforehand:

```
type Helper<T, Fn extends (...args: any[]) => any> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends ReturnType<Fn> ? K : never;
}[keyof T];

type Result = Helper<X, Fn>;
//   ^? "foo"
```

However, a major drawback is that if `X` has multiple keys with the same type,

```
type X = { foo: string; bar: boolean; baz: string };
```

then the result will include all of those keys:

```
type Result = Helper<X, Fn>;
//   ^? "foo" | "baz"
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAGlC8UDeUBmB7dAuKBnYATgJYB2A5gNxQBGAhgTtZgDYS0lQC+FAUAPR8ooSLATI0mHPmLkqdBjRZsSc2gC8phUmS69h0AGIdEAHgAqUCAA9gEEgBNcsAHwAKAG61mAVwg4zAJQIzlBmANoARBjoEQC6vDz6UAASEMyQBOYANFBGljZ2jlCuAHRl9GS4OOwgYbFB8CE1IYhIPFAdUGEA0lCkUADWECDoqKGx-j2x+bYOTgBKEMDeBCRm4BAmRiEA-FC9OCQQ7hAEvJxhQyNjZvE8iRtQi7jezMBiqemnJjA527wCToAPR2PCAA)